# How to check if someone used my desktop or any other device

Tags: physical-access

What can I do to check a potential "evil maid attack"?

Answer (score 1):

Use a stencil to sprinkle some hard-to-see dust in a known pattern.

Place a hair where it will be disturbed.

Routinely display the timestamps of the last two "active" sessions.

Geofence the desktop on your phone, and routinely compare desktop logs with phone logs, looking for activity when you're away.